# I am trying to deploy MEAN application through heroku but i am stuck at a point

Tags: express, heroku

The error i am getting is Refused to load the image https://xxx.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". i am getting 404 error.

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "entnepal"`,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "node Api/server.js",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ng build --prod"
  },
```

My server.js

```
const express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    cors = require('cors'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');
    config = require('./DB');
    const infoRoute = require('./routes/info.route');
    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
    mongoose.connect(config.DB, { useNewUrlParser: true }).then(
      () => {console.log('Database is connected') },
      err => { console.log('Can not connect to the database'+ err)}
    );



const app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "build")); 
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "build", "index.html")); 
});
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(cors());
    app.use('/appointment', infoRoute);
    const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

Procfile
web: node Api/server.js
```

Comment: Where are you seeing the error? During runtime? Or heroku logs?

Comment: The error i am getting is during runtime browser(console) !!! @KrisHollenbeck

Comment: and the error i am getting on heroku logs is no such directories or files to path 'xx/build/index.html '......

Comment: I would solve the heroku logs error first. Looks like your HTML isn't loading properly because it cannot find the path. Maybe try `"/build"`? Also try `console.log()` your path and see what it prints out in the log. I don't know what your project structure is, but if your server file is at the root then you might need to change your path to something like `../build`